# about LRU, How can the operating system know about a memory frame use when it's valid

Tags: hardware, lru, mmu, page-fault, swapfile

In virtual memory, The LRU algorithm is about swapping out page frame which has been the least recently used, but how can the OS know about a frame use since it wont be raising any exception when it is valid ?

Are there use counters of some sort in the MMU or do OSes make regular check by invalidating pages without really swapping them out, only in order to make statistics on the page faults ?

I suppose it might be possible to find the information with Google, but I didn't find the right way to ask it:-/